# $\frac{\ln(x^2)}{\ln(x)} = 2$? Why?

Tags: logarithms

$\frac{\ln(x^2)}{\ln(x)} = 2$?

Upon trying to evaluate $\frac{\ln(x^2)}{\ln(x)}$, i've found that google plots it as always equal to 2, other than 0 where it is undefined. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall the logarithm property
$$\frac{\ln x^2}{\ln x} = \frac{2\ln x}{\ln x} = 2.$$
But this is only true when $x>0$ and $x\neq1$. Otherwise, there is a "hole" there; a removable discontinuity. Notice that this is difficult not to graph, so graphing tools usually just fill the hole/graph over it.

Comment: but if $x\leq0$ $\ln{x}$ is undefined, why have a removable discontinuity?

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran ............ at $x = 1$.

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran There is no plot if $x\leq 0$.

Comment: ok yes thanks, is in $x=1$

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran Ok, glad you understand.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\ln(x^{2})}{\ln(x)} = \frac{2\ln(x)}{\ln(x)} = 2 $$

Comment: How did I not see that beautiful connection. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the change of base formula to write the following.
$$\frac{\ln \left(x^2\right)}{\ln x}=\log_x\!\!\left(x^2\right)=2$$
The above holds for all $x>0,x\neq1$.